# start animation or transition (CSS) when scroll and arrive to a defined pixel

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

How can I activate a transition or animation when I see the element?
The animation or transition is in css. The code is like this:

```
.primo {
    -webkit-animation: mysecond 6s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mysecond 6s;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "I see" ? No user interaction? If the element is below the "fold" then you should assign that class on scroll event (or using carefully a setInterval) when it appears on the viewport

Comment: When I scroll the page and arrive at the right height to see the element.

Comment: do you mean on load of that element you need animation?

Comment: @SergioVento That requires javascript....

Comment: Actually the animation start when the page is loaded

Comment: I need to start the animation when I can see the element, scrolling the page and arriving to the section of the site.

Comment: sorry for the bad english :S

Comment: can u create jsfiddel for you code

Comment: yes http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ej59m4t/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        slider();
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        slider();
    });

    function slider() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 300)
                $('#hidden').stop().animate({"margin-left": '0'});
    }
```

with `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

replace your div with #hidden and the property which is going to change should be placed inside animate

in above example #hidden has margin-left:-200px;  in css

Comment: I have to insert the id or class of the element animated in place of #hidden?

Comment: yes its like that. #hidden will be replaced by your div and its changing value of inside animate

Comment: and what is Margin-left:0?????

Comment: the property which is going to change should be placed inside animate in above example #hidden has margin-left:-200px; in css

Comment: let me create an example i will add the link

Answer (score 1):

Here you are a working example using your class .primo. You should add the class when the element is visible in the viewport. I have made an example where the class with the animation is added when the element is 100px from the top of the viewport, you can adjust that with your values depending when you want the element to be animated.

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/kcpaLbyv/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var offsetTop = 100;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + offsetTop  > $('.theElement').offset().top){
        $('.theElement').addClass('primo');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(element).offset().top<$(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() || $(element).offset().top+$(element).height()>$(window.scrollTop())) {
     // trigger your animation here
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Ah, I forgot to mention to use jQuery

Comment: like this:
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(element).offset().top<$(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() || $(element).offset().top+$(element).height()>$(window.scrollTop())) {
     @-webkit-keyframes mysecond {
    0%   {opacity: 0;}
    25%  {opacity: 0;}
    50%  {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 100;}
}

  }
}

Comment: it's right????????????

Comment: how can I select the height of the page to start the animation????

Comment: No, you are not using javascript there.
Well, this code detect if the element is inside the window, even if only the part of the element, so you don't need the height